# Selfhosted Azure DevOps Agent running as NetworkService not able to complete npm install and npm build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-devops

The agent is not able to build and generate the build folder for react project while using the windows platform with Microsoft and self hosted agent but works fine with ubuntu.

This is the linux yml file with Microsoft agent

https://gist.github.com/yogeswaran-gnrgy/0354d455e6c85d387281eb75d1a326f1

This is the windows yml file with Microsoft agent

https://gist.github.com/yogeswaran-gnrgy/816b9f06dbe0039c07ad1293d2fce141

This is the log generated during the build step using Microsoft agent
https://gist.github.com/yogeswaran-gnrgy/acbc3c2a268ea3b514cc423726b0a751

In case of Self-hosted agent it has both npm and node installed. What can be the problem

Comment: Usually when the pipeline has an error you should notice ##[error] on output. I cannot find an error on your log. Are you sure the pipeline is not completed?

Comment: Pipeline finished but there is no build folder. As you can check in the logs there is no "creating an optimized production build log" Not sure what is the reason

Comment: Maybe you are not on the correct folder on your source code. Before npm run build navigate to the folder that you want to build using npm, or use the path on your agent machine

Comment: I tried to verify if this is a problem with only self-hosted agent turns out it doesn't work with Microsoft hosted agent as well. Using ubuntu-latest it works fine and generates the build folder. When I use the Microsoft hosted agent using windows-latest it is not generating the build folder. I have attached the yml files with both linux and windows. Please check if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux

```
- script: |
    echo Executing install
    npm install
    echo Executing build
    npm run build
  displayName: 'Building the project'
```

When used as script npm install and npm build works fine only in Linux. For windows, it must be like

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Installing dependencies'
  inputs:
      verbose: false
      customCommand: install

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Building the project'
  inputs:
      command: custom
      verbose: false
      customCommand: run build
```